# Serializing a list in model and Deserializing in javascript

Tags: json, deserialization, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to serialize a list of objects in the `OnGet()` method of the model and deserialize it in JavaScript so that I can loop through the objects.

```
public IList<Post> postsList { get; set; }

  
    public string postSerialized { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        

       
        postsList = _db.Posts.ToList();
      
        postSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postsList);
        
    }
```

The parse method isnt working in javascript:

```
<script>
var obj = JSON.parse(@Model.postSerialized);
Console.log(obj);
</script>
```

I believe the issue is in the `@Model.postSeriaized` because it is working in the HTML but not in JavaScript. The string isn't showing any value even when I set the text content of an HTML element to `@Model.postSerialized`.

Eg:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("txt").textContent = @Model.postSerialized;
</script>
```

Note: I have successfully serialized the list into a string but it isn't deserializing.

Comment: what happens when you add the tag [BindProperty]  to the property postSerialized?  I believe this is the issue

Comment: Already tried that. I got it to work, but the JSON result still looks encrypted after being deserialized. And when i try to put it in a var obj it throws an unexpected token error.

Comment: How would you go about serializing a list and deserializing in javascript, is there a better way?

Comment: Personally I would return JsonResult without  serializing it that way, because `return Json(postsList)` would do the job. In the front-end I would use jQuery to make call to Get function. You can check it in this blog post https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/318/working-with-json-in-razor-pages

Comment: I tried the method show in the link you provided, however the jQuery code isnt working: <script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('/Nearby/postslist').done(function (posts) {
        $.each(posts, function (i, post) {
            var item = `<li>
                    <strong>${post}</strong>
                   </li>`;
            $('#posts-list').append(item);
        });
    });
</script>   Note the razor page's name is Nearby, and im using a page handler.

Comment: Am i using the wrong url to call the get method. Btw im not using an interface like in the example, rather im getting the posts list directly from the db and converting it to JSON.